# Pick Up Whispering

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I have a question about "pick up" [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=sz6AO28Z3KkC&pg=PT75&lpg=PT75&dq=%22+picked+up+the+whispering+unconsciously+from+my+visitor%22&source=bl&ots=15VUTk-xns&sig=K9KhYgqRMygh9UdUf0KfPjVdRz0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=P50-VNf7MdDwoAT91IG4CQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22%20picked%20up%20the%20whispering%20unconsciously%20from%20my%20visitor%22&f=false):

> My voice startled me with its sudden loudness. I must have ***picked up the whispering*** unconsciously from my visitor.

Does "*picked up the whispering*" mean something closer to "*pick up information*" or "*pick up a chant*"?

Answer (score 4):

"Picked up" in this instance means "acquired".

The character is suggesting that they, unconsciously, started whispering in response to their visitor's behaviour.

Comment: So, the example is closer to "*pick up the chant*".

Comment: I don't know that phrase. I think a more common example would be to use "pick up" some disease. "I picked up a cold by staying out too long". There's a certain element of the acquisition being unintentional.

Answer (score -1):

In this case "picked up" means something like "noticed"

Comment: Not true, in this case. Given the limited context, it may have been hard to discern, but if you open OP's link you'll see that Dancrumb's analysis is correct.

Comment: I agree with @nmar , your definition fails to highlight the accidental emphasis on the acquisition of the whispers in the first place.